# Generics: Inferred function parameter type

Tags: typescript

I have a function that accepts a configuration object with some state definitions (It's a state machine function).

Example:

```
createStateMachine({
  initial: 'inactive',
  states: {
    inactive: {
      transitions: { ACTIVATE: 'active' },
    },
    active: {
      transitions: { DEACTIVATE: 'inactive' },
      effect(send) {
        // an useless machine, will send back to inactive 
        send('DEACTIVATE') // should only accept "DEACTIVATE", but "ACTIVATE" | "DEACTIVATE" is also good enough.
      },
    },
  },
});
```

It also accepts a function `effect`, with a `send` callback that can be used to trigger state changes. I want `send` parameter type to be a union of the possible transitions inferred from the configuration object itself.

Is this possible with TypeScript?

Comment: You can do [this](https://tsplay.dev/ND5Q8m), but the problem is that the compiler cannot contextually infer the `send` callback parameter type for you at the same time it is inferring the generic types of the state and transition names.  If you are okay refactoring to use intermediate functions to help along the inference, you can do something like [this](https://tsplay.dev/wEV6gN).  Let me know if either or both of those work for you and I can write up an answer; otherwise, please elaborate on what else you're looking for

Comment: Thanks once again @jcalz. I understand - the second version is certainly a good alternative.

What I'm trying to achieve: I'm working on a State Machine Library - I use it at work. Many other libraries out there either don't have typings, or they do but require you to provide a configuration object AND a separate interface to pass as the generic argument. The problem is that now you have to maintain two separate pieces that should be the same. I'm trying to have the state machine infer as much as possible from the config object so it can offer code completion and type safety.

Comment: Here's the Readme in case you want to take a look at the whole API: https://github.com/cassiozen/useStateMachine/blob/main/README.md

Comment: Any way I could make the `on` property optional? Here's what I got so far... https://tsplay.dev/ND5p8m