# Generics and Type Inference in TypeScript

Tags: typescript, typescript-generics

(Follow up to this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67340089/generics-inferred-function-parameter-type?noredirect=1#comment119040191_67340089))

I have a function that accepts a configuration object with some state definitions (It's a state machine function).

Example:

```
const machine = createStateMachine({
  initial: 'inactive',
  states: stateNode({
    inactive: {
      on: { ACTIVATE: 'active' },
    }),
    active: stateNode({
      on: { DEACTIVATE: 'inactive' },
      effect(send) {
        send('DEACTIVATE') // Only accepts "DEACTIVATE".
      },
    }),
  },
});
```

The user can switch the current state by calling `send`, which is available in two places:

- Returned from the `effect` function within the configuration
- Returned from the `createStateMachine` function

I want to infer as much as possible from the configuration, and `stateNode` is an intermediary function that helps with the type inference:

```
function stateNode<T extends Record<keyof T, PropertyKey>>({on, effect}: {
  on: T, effect?: (send: (action: keyof T) => void) => void}) {
  return { on, ...effect && { effect } }
}
```

So far everything works, but I wanted to make the "on" property optional - any ideas?

Here's a [link to a TS Playground with the full code](https://tsplay.dev/mMyedm)

Comment: I don't understand... if you leave out `on`, then you have to leave out `effect` also, right?  Because the `send()` callback would take `never`.  But then your state node is just `{}`, so you don't have to call `stateNode()` explicitly.  Sort of like [this](https://tsplay.dev/wRpkvm).  Does that work how you want it to?  Or am I missing something.

Comment: Fair question, I should have explained it better: An effect can be used to run arbitrary code when the state machine enters or leaves that state. In states that contain  transitions events, you can also `send` an event, but that's not all that can be done within an effect.

So, from that original example, I could have

  frozen: stateNode({
    effect(){ console.log("Entered Frozen") }
  }
}),

Comment: So then, something like [this](https://tsplay.dev/Woqd9N)?  If so I'll try to write up the answer (although I see I didn't get around to the previous question yet)

Comment: I'm ready to accept your answer on the first one, and this one is also perfect! I was trying to use multiple function signature definitions, but couldn't get quite there.
Thanks a lot for all your help, if there's a way, I'd love to buy you a coffee or a beer ;)

Comment: The only thing is that now I'm getting `never` as the param for the function returned by `createStateMachine`

Comment: Oh, I see.  The fact that there is no `on` property declared causes some weirdness; the easiest solution is probably to make it optional and make its type `undefined`... like [this](https://tsplay.dev/w26OYw).  Let me know if there are any further issues

Comment: Fantastic, this is exactly what I needed. 

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Conceptually, all you'd need to do is make `on` optional everywhere it's currently required, and use [the `NonNullable<T>` utility type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/utility-types.html#nonnullabletype) everywhere you are programmatically using the type of `on`, and things would just work:

```
type States<T extends Record<keyof T, { on?: any }>> = { [K in keyof T]: {
  on?: Record<keyof (NonNullable<T[K]['on']>), keyof T>,
  effect?(send: (action: keyof NonNullable<T[K]['on']>) => void): void;
} }

function createStateMachine<
  T extends States<T>>(states: {
    initial: keyof T,
    states: T
  }) {
  return function send(arg: KeysOfTransition<NonNullable<T[keyof T]['on']>>) {
  };
}

function stateNode<T extends Record<keyof T, PropertyKey>>({ on, effect }: {
  on?: T, effect?: (send: (action: keyof T) => void) => void
}) {
  return { ...on && { on }, ...effect && { effect } }
}
```

Unfortunately that doesn't quite work out:

```
const a = createStateMachine({
  initial: 'inactive',
  states: {
    inactive: stateNode({
      on: {
        ACTIVATE: 'active'
      }
    }),
    frozen: stateNode({ effect() { console.log("Entered Frozen") } }), // error!
//  ~~~~~~
// Type 'Record<string | number | symbol, string | number | symbol>' is not assignable to 
// type 'Record<string | number | symbol, "inactive" | "active" | "frozen">'.
    active: stateNode({
      on: {
        DEACTIVATE: 'inactive',
      },
      effect: send => {
        send('DEACTIVATE')
      },
    })
  },
});
// const a: (arg: string | number | symbol) => void
```

The compiler correctly infers `T` when you call `stateNode` with something that has an `on` property, but when you leave it out, the compiler infers `Record<PropertyKey, PropertyKey>`, and that's not what you want at all.  Even if I could make that compile, `PropertyKey` would make the compiler forget all the names of your states, and you'd end up with something useless like `(arg: PropertyKey) => void` coming out of `createStateMachine()`.  You'd like `T` to be `undefined` or `{}` or `Record<never, any>` or something.  Well, I tried playing around with a single call signature for `stateNode`, but contextual typing kept causing `T` to be inferred with this unfortunately wide type.

---

Instead, I'd suggest making `stateNode()` an [overloaded function](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/functions.html#function-overloads) so that we have more control over what happens when you leave out the `on` property:

```
function stateNode<T extends Record<keyof T, PropertyKey>>(param: {
  on: T;
  effect?: ((send: (action: keyof T) => void) => void) | undefined;
}): typeof param;
function stateNode(param: { effect?: () => void, on?: undefined }): typeof param;
function stateNode<T extends Record<keyof T, PropertyKey>>({ on, effect }: {
  on?: T, effect?: (send: (action: keyof T) => void) => void
}) {
  return { ...on && { on }, ...effect && { effect } }
}
```

If you specify `on` when you call `stateNode()`, the first call signature is used and the behavior is the same as before.  If you leave `on` out, the second call signature is used.  Here there is no `T` type to infer at all; instead, the compiler sees `effect` as an optional no-arg function (because, as you said in your comments, this is what you want).  In both cases the output is the same type as the input.  Let's see if this improves things:

```
const a = createStateMachine({
  initial: 'inactive',
  states: {
    inactive: stateNode({
      on: {
        ACTIVATE: 'active'
      }
    }),
    frozen: stateNode({ effect() { console.log("Entered Frozen") } }),
    active: stateNode({
      on: {
        DEACTIVATE: 'inactive',
      },
      effect: send => {
        send('DEACTIVATE')
      },
    })
  },
});
// const a: (arg: "ACTIVATE" | "DEACTIVATE") => void
```

Looks good!

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ts=4.2.3#code/C4TwDgpgBA0hIGcDyAzAKgJwIYDsEEth8B7HAHiQCMArAPigF4orqoIAPYCHAEwSgBKEAMbEMPMgGt4xFMxoAaKAmAZ8OAOb0A-FGkhZ81gC4oOCADcIGANwBYAFCPQkKAGVgWLgjJo2nbj5BETEJfUM0JQBvKFJtU1wQKABfWnomGIBtGCh1PRk5NABdUyjHKFiceODRcSkCqAAKADlSZoBXABtOrEpOiF9sosyAclIRotoASiVwwtoFcrYUFBFgbUaEQNNGrGEiUlM5qFacDu7e-sGYYbGcCenGegtifB4p0xe3+wdklMdHCh2jh9iQcFBhBgIF4IB4YQBZPYAC3UAyWfg4XF4-Dh3l8aU2nm8pSWFXUhHwWE6RwakVJyiJEAQpjQS2SUygZQcFShwHaGHBQJBB3BW14uwwGlMcEQqEwuAIIrIp3OPT6AzQmWOxVG40mjy5FWSP2SAKcDiFoNIsWIYAQuIgrR4Gv8WKCQlqYVpSgAChhbdZQDKCTFSEoICs1ikSdzKtVIstVvtqpttk09iKaQZChyGM9Xu8nlAvjxHOzOUtefzwTEAHT160AMkbnMqKSU9drEaTwCgzdb3ajf1NvzNojwvcoWB4jAhUJhDsRwhR5kahtyOApVNMI3UGfwVhGi1jKhhzIrsbJOH3VlMxFt9sZToga-pFUOF4qX6-AEEAMJoAAkgAaj+aAAKI7jeEAjG+-yXikMz0ig-oAF7cHeD4Os+a6JmsjQcjE44IMQ-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)